# Why would Kim Murphy be scared that her parents bought a piano for Bob?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-killing-of-a-sacred-deer

In *The Killing of a Sacred Deer (2017)*, Bob Murphy says to his sister, Kim Murphy about a piano:

> Bob Murphy: They bought me a piano. Mom told me it'd be here next
>   month. They didn't tell you so **you wouldn't be scared**.

Kim Murphy is a choir singer, why would she be scared of a musical instrument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point in time, the two kids already know one of them will be gone by the next month. They know that their father has to choose. Bob tells Kim about the piano to let her know that he's the one who's going to be around to play the piano the next month. To which Kim requests for his mp3 player after he's dead.

In short, the two kids are arguing as to who will be the the survivor.